# How can I get Price for Size 0.75 , Color = K and Clarity = IF?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My SQL table named "rap_price":

[image: Click here to see my SQL table named "rap_price"]

How can I retrieve PRICE for Size = 0.75 , Color = K, and Purity = IF? Can anyone help me with the SQL query to retrieve price for the above mentioned requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about the question you ask but this might help you.

```
SELECT Price FROM rap_price WHERE Purity='IF' AND Color='K' AND FromSize >= 0.75 AND ToSize <= 0.75
```